# Angular - how do I know which operation has called ngAfterViewChecked()?

Tags: angular

Consider a table, the rows of which are built dynamically - i.e. the HTML element contains an `*ngIf` directive.

On different occassions I want to scroll a selected table row into view. And because these are different occassions and I need the table to be fully built in order for this to work, I am performing this scroll into view operation inside `ngAfterViewChecked()`.

So far, this has worked fine. Now, I have added a `document.click` listener on a different component, not the table, but a component that is on the same page as the table:

```
  @HostListener('document:click')
  documentClick(): void {
    // do something
  }
```

And this seems to be messing with my scrolling into view: When clicking a button, for example, which usually scrolls a selected table into view, `ngAfterViewChecked()` is executed twice, the second time, however, the wrong if-block inside this function is executed.

I wonder, if I could somehow check if `ngAfterViewChecked()` was called by the document.click event, so that I could handle this event inside an additional if-block?

I am also open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll to a table row when the page init you could do the scrolling in the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

The ngAfterViewChecked() is called with every change detection due to lifecycle hooks chain.

[Check here.](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

In addition, you could perform the scroll listening to the click or other event that selects a table row.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I have just tried out to scroll into view in my click-event-handlers. It didn't work initially, but now I have figured it out. Thx!